Issue with Facebook Product Catalog API: Missing Data in Response
I've been making requests to the Product Catalog Products API using this URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/[PRODUCT_CATALOG_ID]/products?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&filter={"name":{"i_contains":"Water"}}&fields=["retailer_id","name","description","price","visibility","inventory","url","image_url"]
Until recently, everything worked fine, but now the response only returns the name field. Here's an example of the response I'm getting:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Water"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "[BEFORE_CURSOR]",
            "after": "[AFTER_CURSOR]"
        },
        "next": "[NEXT_URL]",
        "previous": "[PREVIOUS_URL]"
    }
}

The fields such as description, price, visibility, and others are missing. Has anyone encountered this issue, or are there changes to the API that I may have missed?
